# Coregions in UML

Tags: syntax, uml, modeling, diagrams

What are coregions in UML sequence diagrams?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coregions are used when the sequence of events does not matter, that is they can occur safely in any order.

[This](http://www.sdl-rt.org/standard/V2.2/html/SDL-RTa6.html) is one of the first few pages I found when I searched **coregion sequence diagram** in Google.

Comment: I found that link too, but I wasn't certain if it is relevant, because it is targeted at MSC, not UML.
However it helped, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The coregion is a notational/sytanx choice for representing  parallel CombinedFragments  the UML 2.2 Superstructure spec (14.3.3) says:

> Parallel The interactionOperator par
>   designates that the CombinedFragment
>   represents a parallel merge between
>   the behaviors of the operands. The
>   OccurrenceSpecifications of the
>   different operands can be interleaved
>   in any way as long as the ordering
>   imposed by each operand as such is
>   preserved. A parallel merge defines a
>   set of traces that describes all the
>   ways that OccurrenceSpecifications of
>   the operands may be interleaved
>   without obstructing the order of the
>   OccurrenceSpecifications within the
>   operand.

The answer above is correct this is just more context.

Answer (score 1):

The UML is specified by the OMG in the two documents (http://www.omg.org/spec/uml): The UML Infrastructure and the UML Supestructure. Whatever documentation may be not official.

In the UML superstructure section 14.3.3 it is said:

A notational shorthand for parallel combined fragments are available for the common situation where the order of event occurrences (or other nested fragments) on one Lifeline is insignificant. This means that in a given “coregion” area of a Lifeline all the directly contained fragments are considered separate operands of a parallel combined fragment.